# Where can I write a conditional statement in a react class?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik-material-ui

I have to write a conditional statement to make a certain percentage value green if its positive and red if its negative. But I am not sure where to write this conditional statement.

```
<div>
{this.state.tableData.map((row, index)=>{
return(

<Box component="span" sx={{}}>
<Grid > {row.data.direction}</Grid>
<Grid > ({row.data.marketD}%) today </Grid>
</Box>

)
})}
</div>
```

I need to make `row.data.marketD` show colour.

```
color: {row.data.marketD}<0 ? 'red':'green'.
```

But I have no idea which tag to include this condition in. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the answer as a concept. Your ui library may provide another way.

```
<span style={{color:row.data.MarketD<0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}>{row.data.marketD}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the condition statement should be inside the square of practice.

```
{row.data.marketD < 0 ? 'red':'green' }
```

Comment: what tag should this condition be in?

Comment: Which element do you want to add this style?

Comment: A <Grid> </Grid>

Comment: Which library does this element belong to?

Comment: <Grid sx={{color:row.data.marketD<0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}>({row.data.marketD}%) today </Grid>
This worked. It belongs to Material UI.

Comment: Great, Good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to wrap your text in a `Typography` component and change the color attribute based on your condition. In this way you isolate you text from the rest of the content content of the `Grid` (it will not affect the `today` text beside it):

```
<Typography color={row.data.MarketD<0 ? 'red' : 'green'}>
    Your text here
</Typography>
```